# How to create custom view showing all User Stories that I have a task on

Tags: rally

I am a DBA and I work across all of our dev teams.  I often will get a task on someone else's user story.  I will not be a member of the team that the user story belongs to.  I need a way to see all of the user stories that I have a task on so that I can easily track the status, etc of the overall user story.

We are using Rally/Agile-Central

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use the Custom List app and go to a location in the project hierarchy above anywhere you might have a story or task assigned to you. If you then ask it to filter on owner equals you, then it will give you the stories you own, but also the stories owned by someone else that you have a task assigned to you.

It does the equivalent of this query for you automatically:

((Owner = daniel@acme.com) or (Tasks.Owner = daniel@acme.com))